# how to show roulette wheel format in an easiest way in R

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGt3Y.png)I would like to write a script to show the roulette wheel numbers in my screen as the casino's order, like first row is 3,6,9,----36, and second row is 2,5,8,----35,  and the third row is 1,4,7,---34. 
I have written something

```
a= seq(3,36,3) 
b= seq(2,35,3) 
c=seq(1,34,3) 
print (rbind(a,b,c))
```

but it maybe not the most efficient way, so does anyone have an exactly best answer?

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far

Comment: here we go:      a= seq(3,36,3)
b= seq(2,35,3)
c=seq(1,34,3)
print (rbind(a,b,c))

Comment: How exactly do you want to "show" these numbers on a screen?

Comment: like, i want to make it as a background photo on my laptop. thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please include code and example of desired output. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have added the code, see modified one. thanks

Comment: that's only the data

Comment: just like that and set it as the background photo in my laptop, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`matrix(1:36,ncol=12)[3:1,]` gives you:

```
> matrix(1:36,ncol=12)[3:1,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30    33    36
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26    29    32    35
[3,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25    28    31    34
```

which is the same layout as your code but without row labels.

Its just a matrix with 12 columns with flipped rows via the `[3:1,]` index.

If you want to make an image of that then I suggest you use a screengrab program.

Comment: omg, so cool, you made it. that is what i supposed to see. appreciate that.